# Iterate in order different list items to match height

Tags: jquery, each

I'm looking to standardize rows of 3 lists.

What I'm trying to figure out is how to iterate row by row to make the heights equal as they appear on the front end.
The number of items will always be equal and would like to make the height of each `li` equal based on largest in each iteration.

So for example :

```
<div class="column-1-here">
  <ul>
    <li>Test<br />Test<br/>Test<li>
    <li>test></li>
  </ul>
</div>
/*These lists are aligned side by side and I'd like to make sure the heights are equal. It's also possible I'd add another 1 or 2 lists.*/
<div class="column-2-here">
  <ul>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test<br />Test</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Any base ideas on how this would be tackled if I'm looking to run `.each()` in almost a comparative way?

This is what I have so far. The issue at this point is the height isn't adjusting to the largest height. Again these are in order – so the first li in column-1-here should be the same height as the first li in column-2-here :

```
var listItems = $("#firstTab li");
var max_height = 0;
listItems.each(function() {
  if( $(this).height() > max_height )
    max_height = $(this).height();  
    // and the rest of your code
    listItems.css( "height", max_height+'px' );
});
```

Comment: I made it row by row... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

Okay... To set heights row by row, it get a bit more complicated.
But nothing is impossible!

```js
var lists = $(document).find("ul");
var cells = $(document).find("li");
var colCount = lists.length;
var rowCount = lists.first().find("li").length;

var heights={};


// Get the tallest height per row
for(i=0;i<rowCount;i++){
  heights["row_"+i] = 0;

  for(j=0;j<colCount;j++){
    if( heights["row_"+i] < lists.eq(j).find("li").eq(i).height() ){
      heights["row_"+i] = lists.eq(j).find("li").eq(i).height();
    }
  }
}

// Apply new height to each cell of a row
for(i=0;i<cells.length;i++){
  cells.eq(i).height(heights["row_"+i%rowCount])
}
```

```css
div{
  float:left;
}
li{
  border:1px solid black;
  padding:6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="column-1-here">
  <ul>
    <li>
      Test<br>
      Test<br>
      Test
    </li>
    <li>Test</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!--These lists are aligned side by side and I'd like to make sure the heights are equal. It's also possible I'd add another 1 or 2 lists.-->
<div class="column-2-here">
  <ul>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>
      Test<br>
      Test
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

**First answer**

First, there was a couple minor syntax issues in your HTML...
And `#firstTab` was not present.

But I figured out what you want.
You were close.

You only have to move this line : `listItems.css( "height", max_height+'px' );`
out of the `.each()` loop.

```js
var listItems = $("[class^=column] li");
var max_height = 0;
listItems.each(function() {
  if( $(this).height() > max_height )
    max_height = $(this).height();  
  // and the rest of your code
  
});
listItems.css( "height", max_height+'px' );
```

```css
div{
  float:left;
}
li{
  border:1px solid black;
  padding:6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="column-1-here">
  <ul>
    <li>
      Test<br>
      Test<br>
      Test
    </li>
    <li>Test</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!--These lists are aligned side by side and I'd like to make sure the heights are equal. It's also possible I'd add another 1 or 2 lists.-->
<div class="column-2-here">
  <ul>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>
      Test<br>
      Test
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have any element with id `firstTab` in your HTML code. I added it and worked fine. By the way, I recommend to keep the setting height part out of the loop. If you would like to apply this adjustment on more than one list, you can use a `class` selector instead of `id` selector. Like `.adjustedTab`

```js
var listItems = $("#firstTab li");
var max_height = 0;
$.each(listItems, function(key, val) {
   if( $(this).height() > max_height ) {
       max_height = $(this).height();  
   }
});
listItems.css( "height", max_height+'px' );
console.log(max_height);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="column-1-here">
  <ul>
    <li>Test<br />Test<br/>Test<li>
    <li>test></li>
  </ul>
</div>
/*These lists are aligned side by side and I'd like to make sure the heights are equal. It's also possible I'd add another 1 or 2 lists.*/
<div class="column-2-here" id="firstTab">
  <ul>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test<br />Test</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: lol! No answer for more than an hour and Bang! Two answers saying the same thing within 2 minutes... Funny!

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette, according to the comment in the code, I added only for the second list. btw, I updated the answer

Comment: OP wants all `li` at the same height based on the tallest. The second is floating. OP said *«aligned side by side»*... It can't mean something else.

Comment: Woah. It's alway something small. One question for ya'll though. I'm looking to parse by "row"in essence. So the first row could be only 1 "test" and that entire row would be the height of only 1 row". The next could be uneven ect. It will never be the same. It looks like I may have been wrong somewhere as it looks like each are the exact same height no matter what. Does that make sense?